# instafeed.js user don't work

Tags: javascript, instagram

I have downloaded instafeed.js and set up everything, it works with the code when I'm tagging a tag, but I want to have my instafeed from my account.
But it doesn't work, only when I use tagged:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var feed = new Instafeed ({
     get: 'tagged',
     tagName: 'angodesign',
     limit: '10',
     clientId: '###443333'
   });
   feed.run(); 
</script>
```

What am i doing wrong? 
I have write my access token and the `userId` but it won't work..

Answer (score 0):

Instafeed.js won't work for the following reasons:

1. If your user account visibility is set to "Private". Please make your
   account public and try again.
2. You may need an accessToken to allow you to pull from your user feed.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of anyone else coming across this. This is what you want for your account to be linked.

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId:  *******,
    clientId: '****a****v****b****',
    accessToken: '***d**.sd**fs**.**************',
    limit: 12,
    resolution: 'low_resolution',
    template: '<div class="col3"><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" style="background-image: url({{image}});" class="zoom instagram-{{orientation}}"></a></div>',
    useHttp: true
});
feed.run();
```

Obviously put your userID, AccessToken, and clientId for your insta-gram account.

If you dont know where to get these, here's how:

**clientID**: Go to https://www.instagram.com/developer/. Sign in into your account and click "Register your application", fill in the blanks. Once done, go to manage clients located on the top right hand side and you can see your clientID.

**Access Token**: Go to this url http://instagramwordpress.rafsegat.com/docs/get-access-token/. Scroll down and click "Click here to get your Access Token!". It should reload, scroll down again and you will see your access token.

**UserId**: Now that you have your accessToken, you can put this url in your browsers address bar, https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=[USERNAME]&access_token=[ACCESS TOKEN]. Replace [USERNAME] with your username and [ACCES TOKEN], with your access token. You should get an object with your id in there.

Heres another way to get userID. Put this url in your browsers address bar.https://www.instagram.com/EXAMPLEUSERNAMEGOESHERE/?__a=1.Do you see where i typed EXAMPLEUSERNAMEGOESHERE? Replace that with your instagram username please. And do a ctrl f for "id" and your user id should be in the key value pair. Something like this "owner": {"id": "123456789"}.

Once you get those 3 things in your instafeed configuration with the instafeed script linked of course. It should just load up! I hoped this helped.